# Where should I ask about the sevenfold Spirit of God?

Tags: discussion, scope

> One of the things I've been wondering about is the sevenfold Spirit (or the seven Spirits) of God.
>
> Do the seven Spirits refer to one member of the Godhead, the Holy Spirit?  Do they represent different aspects (facets) of the (one) Spirit of God?
>
> In other words, the seven Spirits are God, not created spirit beings that serve God?

Does that represent the right form of question?

<s>Should I be asking about this on C.SE or BH.SE?</s>

**Update:**

Thanks for helping me to properly word this question.

I don't know what the different views might be, so I couldn't ask what a biblical basis would be for a particular view.  Not having an understanding of this, I would benefit from an overview.

Comment: I'd recommend an initial question on BH.SE asking what is meant in the Revelation passages. Then once you get some answers you can ask a follow up question.

Answer (score 6):

On Christianity.SE you can ask:

- What is an overview of beliefs about the sevenfold spirit of God?
- What does group X teach about the sevenfold spirit of God?

But to be honest I don't think you'll get good answers for either of these because the topic isn't one which has clear divisional positions (unlike baptism for example). Still, big groups like Catholicism have written about nearly everything so they're sure to have something if you asked for their perspective.

On Hermeneutics.SE you can ask:

- What is meant by "seven spirits of God" in Revelation 1:4, 3:1 etc?
- What is the likely pre-NT background to Revelation's use of "seven spirits of God"? (ie, what stuff in the OT or other pre-NT writings is John likely alluding to?)

Answer (score 5):

[I assume you are talking about this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Spirits_of_God)

Eschatology is a tricky subject on this site. You have really only three options for eschatology questions on this site:

1. **What is the Biblical Basis for this belief?** - How do people holding a certain view use the Bible to support it.
2. **What does some specific group teach or believe about this subject?** *or rephrased* **How do they interpret these verses?** - If you are fond a particular Christian group, this question type will be easy to formulate and you will get official answers from that group's publications (assuming they exist).
3. **What is an overview of the beliefs regarding this subject?** - Asking a generalized question about something is a little trickier. The community does allow overview questions, and if it's not too broad of a subject you should get some nice answers.

Without knowing more about what you want to learn about this topic I can't give more specific advice.

Comment: `Without knowing more about what you want to learn about this topic I can't give more specific advice.` That's key. Petah, what you might want to do is show us what you want to ask, and we'll tell you where it can go and/or how to reword it to work on this site.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this an eschatology question. You can ask about the sevenfold spirit without any future sense.